# How can we change the location of our real iphone device?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I already used the gpx file in our iphone project by setting the longitude and latitude. And it worked fine for me but it only works if i create a debug version of app in my device but as soon as we disconnect the device from our mac in which the xcode is present, the iphone reset itself to the current location.

Is there any other way we can set the geolocation of our iphone device and test our application which has some features related to geofencing or geolocations.

Answer (score 1):

This can't be done. Location simulation only works while the device is plugged in and the app is being debugged.